# Android SQLite COLLATE NOCASE syntax error

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am searching in the database and I want to get the data in any case (UPPER lower or Mix). I found out that `COLLATE NOCASE` would do the trick but it is causing an error.

As you can see the query here ...

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "COLLATE_NOCASE": syntax
>   error (code 1): , while compiling:

```
Select 
    _ID, Name, Surname, Username, Password, Roll 
From
    USER 
Where 
    name = 'Danyal Ahmed' 
    and surname = 'CHAUDHRY' COLLATE_NOCASE;
```

Any help is appreciated.

> 03-04 23:41:06.760 28952-28952/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>                                                      Process: com.example.danyalahmed.stockmanagement, PID: 28952
>                                                      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "COLLATE_NOCASE": syntax
>   error (code 1): , while compiling: Select _ID, Name, Surname,
>   Username, Password, Roll FROM USER where name = 'Danyal Ahmed' and
>   surname = 'CHAUDHRY' COLLATE_NOCASE;
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:895)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:506)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
>                                                          at com.example.danyalahmed.stockmanagement.Classes.DbAdapter.getData(DbAdapter.java:113)
>                                                          at com.example.danyalahmed.stockmanagement.Activities.Users$1.onItemSelected(Users.java:83)
>                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:914)
>                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:903)
>                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:48)
>                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:873)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)

Comment: Ah, by the way I have tried with COLLATE NOCASE without underscore, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Without really knowing anything about it, isn't your mistake simply that it should be 2 words instead of `COLLATE_NOCASE`?. I.e. `COLLATE nocase`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's "COLLATE NOCASE" without underscores.

Comment: Help is appreciated.

Comment: worked like this, surname COLLATE NOCASE = 'CHAUDHRY'. Thanks guys